# How does one find out the options set by "-target" with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

The ffmpeg [documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) says the following about `-target`:

> Specify target file type (`vcd`, `svcd`, `dvd`, `dv`, `dv50`). type may be prefixed with `pal-`, `ntsc-` or `film-` to use the corresponding standard. All the format options (bitrate, codecs, buffer sizes) are then set automatically.

How does one find out the exact options set "automatically" by a particular `-target` option, such as `pal-dvd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a very old question, but recently I ran into the same problem and even though the answer marked here as correct gave me the clues to solve it. It turns out that looking for a parameter that you couldn't find in the ffmpeg code turns out that all these parameters exist in the same ffmpeg help page, which is easier to find than having to go through a large amount of code that is constantly being updated.

[FFmpeg Main Options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Main-options)

```
VCD

pal:
-f vcd -muxrate 1411200 -muxpreload 0.44 -packetsize 2324
-s 352x288 -r 25
-codec:v mpeg1video -g 15 -b:v 1150k -maxrate:v 1150k -minrate:v 1150k -bufsize:v 327680
-ar 44100 -ac 2
-codec:a mp2 -b:a 224k

ntsc:
-f vcd -muxrate 1411200 -muxpreload 0.44 -packetsize 2324
-s 352x240 -r 30000/1001
-codec:v mpeg1video -g 18 -b:v 1150k -maxrate:v 1150k -minrate:v 1150k -bufsize:v 327680
-ar 44100 -ac 2
-codec:a mp2 -b:a 224k

film:
-f vcd -muxrate 1411200 -muxpreload 0.44 -packetsize 2324
-s 352x240 -r 24000/1001
-codec:v mpeg1video -g 18 -b:v 1150k -maxrate:v 1150k -minrate:v 1150k -bufsize:v 327680
-ar 44100 -ac 2
-codec:a mp2 -b:a 224k

SVCD

pal:
-f svcd -packetsize 2324
-s 480x576 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25
-codec:v mpeg2video -g 15 -b:v 2040k -maxrate:v 2516k -minrate:v 0 -bufsize:v 1835008 -scan_offset 1
-ar 44100
-codec:a mp2 -b:a 224k

ntsc:
-f svcd -packetsize 2324
-s 480x480 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30000/1001
-codec:v mpeg2video -g 18 -b:v 2040k -maxrate:v 2516k -minrate:v 0 -bufsize:v 1835008 -scan_offset 1
-ar 44100
-codec:a mp2 -b:a 224k

film:
-f svcd -packetsize 2324
-s 480x480 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 24000/1001
-codec:v mpeg2video -g 18 -b:v 2040k -maxrate:v 2516k -minrate:v 0 -bufsize:v 1835008 -scan_offset 1
-ar 44100
-codec:a mp2 -b:a 224k

DVD

pal:
-f dvd -muxrate 10080k -packetsize 2048
-s 720x576 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25
-codec:v mpeg2video -g 15 -b:v 6000k -maxrate:v 9000k -minrate:v 0 -bufsize:v 1835008
-ar 48000
-codec:a ac3 -b:a 448k

ntsc:
-f dvd -muxrate 10080k -packetsize 2048
-s 720x480 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30000/1001
-codec:v mpeg2video -g 18 -b:v 6000k -maxrate:v 9000k -minrate:v 0 -bufsize:v 1835008
-ar 48000
-codec:a ac3 -b:a 448k

film:
-f dvd -muxrate 10080k -packetsize 2048
-s 720x480 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 24000/1001
-codec:v mpeg2video -g 18 -b:v 6000k -maxrate:v 9000k -minrate:v 0 -bufsize:v 1835008
-ar 48000
-codec:a ac3 -b:a 448k

DV

pal:
-f dv
-s 720x576 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25
-ar 48000 -ac 2

ntsc:
-f dv
-s 720x480 -pix_fmt yuv411p -r 30000/1001
-ar 48000 -ac 2

film:
-f dv
-s 720x480 -pix_fmt yuv411p -r 24000/1001
-ar 48000 -ac 2

The dv50 target is identical to the dv target except that the pixel format set is yuv422p for all three standards.
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, only by looking at the source code. Check out [`ffmpeg_opt.c` starting from line 2084](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/ffmpeg_opt.c#L2084). Here you'll find the options for each target.

For example, for `dvd`:

```
opt_video_codec(o, "c:v", "mpeg2video");
opt_audio_codec(o, "c:a", "ac3");
parse_option(o, "f", "dvd", options);

parse_option(o, "s", norm == PAL ? "720x576" : "720x480", options);
parse_option(o, "r", frame_rates[norm], options);
parse_option(o, "pix_fmt", "yuv420p", options);
av_dict_set(&o->g->codec_opts, "g", norm == PAL ? "15" : "18", AV_DICT_DONT_OVERWRITE);

av_dict_set(&o->g->codec_opts, "b:v", "6000000", AV_DICT_DONT_OVERWRITE);
av_dict_set(&o->g->codec_opts, "maxrate", "9000000", AV_DICT_DONT_OVERWRITE);
av_dict_set(&o->g->codec_opts, "minrate", "0", AV_DICT_DONT_OVERWRITE); // 1500000;
av_dict_set(&o->g->codec_opts, "bufsize", "1835008", AV_DICT_DONT_OVERWRITE); // 224*1024*8;

av_dict_set(&o->g->format_opts, "packetsize", "2048", AV_DICT_DONT_OVERWRITE);  // from www.mpucoder.com: DVD sectors contain 2048 bytes of data, this is also the size of one pack.
av_dict_set(&o->g->format_opts, "muxrate", "10080000", AV_DICT_DONT_OVERWRITE); // from mplex project: data_rate = 1260000. mux_rate = data_rate * 8

av_dict_set(&o->g->codec_opts, "b:a", "448000", AV_DICT_DONT_OVERWRITE);
parse_option(o, "ar", "48000", options);
```